# Firebase RecyclerView Will Not Retreive Items from Database and Display them on Screen. Screen is Empty

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview

I am trying display some of my items from my database into my Recyclerview. However, nothing will display on my screen. I have confirmed that the items are in the database. I have looked at other questions on StackOverflow, I have added the On Start Listening and the OnStop Listening, but nothing seems to work. I would really appreciate any assistance that would get me to the right direction. Thank you in advance.

**Model Class**

```
<public class Posting_Class {
    private String firstname;
    private String lastname;
    private String profileimage;
    private String user_post;

    public Posting_Class() {}


    public Posting_Class(String firstname, String lastname, String profileimage, String user_post) {

        this.firstname = firstname;
        this.lastname = lastname;
        this.profileimage = profileimage;
        this.user_post = user_post;

    }

    public String getUser_post() {
        return user_post;
    }

    public void setUser_post(String user_post) {
        this.user_post = user_post;
    }

    public String getFirstname() {
        return firstname;
    }

    public void setFirstname(String firstname) {
        this.firstname = firstname;
    }

    public String getLastname() {
        return lastname;
    }

    public void setLastname(String lastname) {
        this.lastname = lastname;
    }

    public String getProfileimage() {
        return profileimage;
    }

    public void setProfileimage(String profileimage) {
        this.profileimage = profileimage;
    }
}
```

XML With the RecylerView Layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/main_recycle_view_post"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:padding="20dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">


            <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
                android:id="@+id/recycle_view_user_image"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="65dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="268dp"
                android:src="@drawable/profile_place_holder"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/options_menu"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/recycle_view_first_name"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
                android:text="First Name"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/recycle_view_user_image"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />


            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/recycle_view_last_name"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="90dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
                android:text="Last Name"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/recycle_view_user_image"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/post_date"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:text="Blog Post Date and Time"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/recycle_view_user_image"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/recycle_view_first_name" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/recycle_view_image"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="200dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/post_words_placeholder"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_rectangle" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/post_words_placeholder"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="45dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
                android:text="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, soluta regione urbanitas vis in, qui elit populo ut. "
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/post_date" />


            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/comment_count"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                android:text="0"
                android:textSize="18dp"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/comment_icon"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/recycle_view_image"
                app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.876" />


            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/comment_icon"
                android:layout_width="28dp"
                android:layout_height="24dp"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_speech_bubble"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/comment_count"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/recycle_view_image"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="16dp"
                tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="403dp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/peace_sign_count"
                android:layout_width="24dp"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="1dp"
                android:text="0"
                android:textSize="18dp"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/recycle_view_image" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/peace_sign_icon"
                android:layout_width="30dp"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/peace_sign_count"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/recycle_view_image"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_win" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/options_menu"
                android:layout_width="22dp"
                android:layout_height="25dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="23dp"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/recycle_view_user_image"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_menu" />


        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>>
```

View Holder:

```
public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        View mView;

    public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {

        super(itemView);
        mView = itemView;

        itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                mClickListener.onItemClick(view, getAdapterPosition());
            }
        });
    }    

    public void setDetails(Context ctx, String firstname, String lastname, String profileimage, String user_post) {

        //Views//
        TextView mPost_words = mView.findViewById(R.id.post_words_placeholder);
        TextView mpostfirstname = mView.findViewById(R.id.recycle_view_first_name);
        TextView mpostlastname = mView.findViewById(R.id.recycle_view_last_name);
        CircleImageView mpost_user_profile_picture = mView.findViewById(R.id.recycle_view_user_image);
        ImageView recycle_place_holder = mView.findViewById(R.id.recycle_view_image);
        TextView comment_count = mView.findViewById(R.id.comment_count);
        ImageView comment_icon = mView.findViewById(R.id.comment_icon);
        ImageView peace_icon = mView.findViewById(R.id.peace_sign_icon);
        TextView peace_count = mView.findViewById(R.id.peace_sign_count);
        ImageView recycle_view_menu_icon = mView.findViewById(R.id.options_menu);
        TextView recycle_view_date_time = mView.findViewById(R.id.post_date);
        //Views//

        //set data to views//
        mPost_words.setText(user_post);
        mpostfirstname.setText(firstname);
        mpostlastname.setText(lastname);
        Picasso.get().load(profileimage).into(mpost_user_profile_picture);
        //set data to views//
    }
    private ViewHolder.ClickListener mClickListener;

    public interface ClickListener {
        void onItemClick(View view,int position);
    }

    public void setOnClickListener(ViewHolder.ClickListener clickListener) {

        mClickListener = clickListener;
    }
}
```

Adapter:

```
<private void show_data_from_firebase() {
        Query query = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()
                .getReference()
                .child("Users");

        options = new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<Posting_Class>().setQuery(UsersReference, Posting_Class.class).build();
        firebaseRecyclerAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Posting_Class, ViewHolder>(options) {
            @Override
            protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position, @NonNull Posting_Class posting_class) {

                holder.setDetails(getApplicationContext(),posting_class.getFirstname(),posting_class.getLastname(),posting_class.getProfileimage(),posting_class.getUser_post());
            }

            @NonNull
            @Override
            public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

                View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.recycleview_layout_activity_wall, parent, false);
                ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(itemView);

                viewHolder.setOnClickListener(new ViewHolder.ClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onItemClick(View view, int position) {
                        Toast.makeText(Personal_Wall.this, "Hello", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);

                    }
                });

                return viewHolder;

            }
        };

        firebaseRecyclerAdapter.startListening();
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(firebaseRecyclerAdapter);
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

    }


    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        firebaseRecyclerAdapter.startListening();
    }


    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        if (firebaseRecyclerAdapter !=null) {
            firebaseRecyclerAdapter.stopListening();
        }

    }
```

Some of the Activity XML With The RecycleView Included:

```
        </FrameLayout>

        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/my_recycle_view_for_posts"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:paddingTop="40dp"
            android:paddingLeft="20dp"
            android:paddingRight="20dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="100dp"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text= "This is text to make the screen scroll"
            android:textColor="#000"
            android:layout_marginTop="400dp"
            />

    </LinearLayout>
```

Images database:
[image]

Comment: Please add your database structure as a JSON file or at least a screenshot.

Comment: Thank you- I am not able to show it on my post for some reason, but here is the link that stackoverflow generated. https://i.stack.imgur.com/LSIV9.png

Comment: @JasmineSlater where is the Banner Images come from?

Comment: Oh sorry, thats for something else. That part is working. But I dont want to pull that from the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You already created query for it, but you did not use it.

```
Query query = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users");
//Here is your mistake, changed to query (before this UserReference)
options = new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<Posting_Class>().setQuery(query, Posting_Class.class).build();
```

Updated:

Add this attributes into your class.

```
private String firstname;
private String lastname;
private String profileimage;
private String user_post;
private String bannerImage; //Add here
```

After that, if you want to store the data, you can set as null.

Comment: Thank you. I will try to see if that fixes it.

Comment: Unfortunately, that didnt work but thank you for your suggestion.

Comment: Unfortunately, I have not yet solved the problem. I was thinking that maybe the issue could be that in my recycleview xml, I have some imageview and textview that were not in the database. So im going to delete those items, and see if that works. Please let me know if you have any other thoughts. thank you for your help!

Comment: You have problem with the banner image. please add this inside your model class too @JasmineSlater

Comment: hmm. i dont want the banner image for the recycleview. is it necessary to have? I just need it for another section of the app.- Thank you for your help.

Comment: @JasmineSlater I updated the answer. if this problem still not solve, tell me

Comment: @JasmineSlater you can tick 'yes' if answer is correct